# CRM2011 How to get object type code by entity name in Javascript?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a lookup field in the form, before select the related entity for the lookup, I check some conditions, if not pass, I overwrite the lookup onclick event to alert user; else, I need to overwrite the onclick event to show the lookup window to allow user to select entity.

So I need the object type code of this lookup, but before select there is no value then I can't get the object type code by use this code: *var objecttypecode = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("field id").getValue()[0].type;*

How to get object type code by entity name?

Comment: I find out the way:

`function GetObjectTypeCode(entityName) {


    try {

        var lookupService = new RemoteCommand("LookupService", "RetrieveTypeCode");
        lookupService.SetParameter("entityName", entityName);
        var result = lookupService.Execute();

        if (result.Success && typeof result.ReturnValue == "number") {
            return result.ReturnValue;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}`

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find out the way:

```cs
function GetObjectTypeCode(entityName) {
    try {
        var lookupService = new RemoteCommand("LookupService", "RetrieveTypeCode");
        lookupService.SetParameter("entityName", entityName);
        var result = lookupService.Execute();

        if (result.Success && typeof result.ReturnValue == "number") {
            return result.ReturnValue;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may work now, to my best knowledge, using RemoteCommand in custom code has always been unsupported and is not guaranteed to always work.

Comment: The **GetObjectTypeCode(entityName)** method mentioned above will not work in a HTML web resource because a HTML web resource is always contained within an IFrame & calling the CRM methods becomes a challenge.

Comment: @GCATNM: While you are absolutely right, I think the simplicity & lightweightnes of the RemoteCommand justifies this approach above the RetrieveEntityMetaData approach

Comment: @Arsenal: The justification of using unsupported and undocumented APIs is debatable. If simplicity outweighs putting oneself (and a potential customer) at the risk of having your code broken by future CRM updates, that may "justify" it for the individual. I highly doubt it can be called good practice if you're concerned with quality and reliability.

Answer (score 0):

One of the supported way of doing this is using the Metadata service and then retrieving the Object Type Code or etc (entity Type Code).